# How do I use the AutodiscoverUrl method?

Tags: ews-javascript-api

I'm trying to use the ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl() method, but it's not working.  It doesn't seem to be getting a URL, resulting in  the error "Cannot read property 'AbsoluteUri' of undefined" from ExchangeCredentials.GetUriWithoutSuffix.

Here is my code ('c' is just a json object):

```
service = new EwsJS.ExchangeService(EwsJS.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016);
service.Credentials = new EwsJS.ExchangeCredentials(c.UserName, c.Password);
service.AutodiscoverUrl("email@domain.com", RedirectCallback);

// I'm forcing the accepted redirect here.
function RedirectCallback(url) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I think I've found the issue.  The authorization headers are not being added to the xhrOptions during the autodiscover GET call, which is resulting in an empty result instead of the valid endpoint URL.  Diving further into the code revealed that it's trying to look up ".../autodiscover/autodiscover.xml" even though I'm using an Exchange Server version newer than 2007, which should be using ".../autodiscover/autodiscover.svc" instead.  Is this a bug?  Is there a workaround to force autodiscover to always use Soap Http instead of Legacy Http endpoint?

Comment: For some reason credentials aren't being passed to the autodiscover service, which is resulting in a 401 error that's not being handled.  Considering this line of code I found, I'm guessing this is part of the problem: "//todo - optimize code, need to apply logic in failed errors as 401 go to onerror of xhr;"   How do I ensure that credentials are passed to the GET request?  Or is this a feature that is not available?

Answer (score 1):

<del>Autodiscover in `ews-javascript-api` needs major re-write to work properly.</del>

Autodiscover is re-written, latest dev build is out with `@next` tag.
you can now use it when installing `npm i ews-javascript-api@next`, once stable build is out you can install regular build.

```
 var Service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);   
 Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(user, pass);

 //Autodiscover
 Service.AutodiscoverUrl(user, this.RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
 console.log(Service.Url);
```